# Do I get the elements in Dictionary in a FIFO way with foreach in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have C# Dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
map["x"] = "1";
map["z"] = "2";
map["y"] = "0";
```

When I get the keys with `foreach`, I get the value of "x"-"z"-"y". And this is the sequence that I give input to the map.

```
foreach (var pair in map)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
}
```

Is this guaranteed behavior? I mean, with Dictionary, do I always get the elements in FIFO way with foreach?

Comment: Did my answer help ? If not, perhaps you can explain what you're hoping to achieve ultimately. There may be a better way to resolve your issue, if you know there is an importance to FIFO ordering that you've observed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, A dictionary is not guaranteed to order its contents in the way they were inserted.

To quote the blurb from MSDN:

'For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue) structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.'

Comment: It might help to look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx and compare the various OrderBy overloads to see if one of them suits your needs.

Answer (score -1):

They are typically ordered by the key - x, y, z in your case.

Comment: There's absolutely no guarantee the they will be enumerated in any specific order